# увеличение блока при наведении курсора мыши

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении курсора на блок он увеличивался вправо и наверх как бы. Я сделал так:

css:

```
.test {
    background:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
 cursor:url(http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif), auto;
}
.test:hover {
         transform-origin: left top;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  transition: margin-left 130ms;
  transition: margin-top 130ms;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

но почему-то не работает. Как сделать отступ, чтобы при наведении блок как бы увеличивался т.е как бы становился больше? [image]
Как на этой картинке. Тут 4 блока и видно насколько первый блок больше при наведении. Мне нужно прям как там, помогите если можете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй transform: scale()

С помощью функции scale() свойства transform можно увеличивать и уменьшать объекты на веб-странице. Принцип работы заключается в масштабировании элемента по горизонтали и вертикали с указанием коэффициента масштабирования. Пример:

transform: scale(3); /* пропорциональное увеличение элемента в 3 раза */

transform: scale(0.5); /* пропорциональное уменьшение элемента наполовину */

Comment: @CapitalNemo я написал так вы сказали, и это помогло, но блок прозрачный, то есть как сделать перекрывание? Чтобы он перекрывал нижний блок? Спасибо.

Comment: Чтобы сделать один блок поверх другого нужно использовать для них обоих
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
Вот как здесь: http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index

Comment: @CapitalNemo, не помогло почему-то(

Comment: https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/45/run/19
Пример как блок перекриваєт другой

Answer (score 1):

Что-то такое желаете получить?

```css
.content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  min-height: 120px;
  height: 40vh;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: green;
  transition: transform .15s;
}

.item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.item.l-t {
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.item.r-t {
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.item.l-b {
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.item.r-b {
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item l-t"></div>
  <div class="item r-t"></div>
  <div class="item l-b"></div>
  <div class="item r-b"></div>
</div>
```